# I'm trying to make a hangman type game. I cant figure out how to get the info from the textbox and evaluate the data

Tags: c#, random

Im making a hangman type game. So far it is generating a random word and displays the mystery word. Now I'm trying to allow players to input letter guesses and I need the program to evaluate the letters to see its in the mystery word.

Then if the word is there, and they get it correct, I need to input that letter into the correct position.

I can't figure it out. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
public partial class wordGuess : Form
{
    private int wrong = 0;
    private int currentLetter;
    private int currentWord;
    private string words;

    public wordGuess()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadwords()
    {
        //random object//
        Random rand = new Random();

        //array for words//
        List<string> words = new List<string> { "apricot", "sword", "alien", "outerspace", "impossible", "clouds", "crayons", "science" };
        int index = rand.Next(words.Count);
        String mysteryword = words[index];

        foreach (char l in mysteryword)
        {
            lblRandWord.Text += "*";
        }
    }

    private void picHang_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnLetterG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int letter;

        letter = Convert.ToChar(txtLetter.Text.Substring(0, 1));

        if (wrong == 1)
        {
            picHeart1.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (wrong == 2)
        {
            picHeart1.Visible = false;
            picHeart2.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (wrong == 3)
        {
            picHeart1.Visible = false;
            picHeart2.Visible = false;
            picHeart3.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (wrong == 4)
        {
            picHeart1.Visible = false;
            picHeart2.Visible = false;
            picHeart3.Visible = false;
            picHeart4.Visible = false;
        }

        else if (wrong == 5)
        {
            picHeart1.Visible = false;
            picHeart2.Visible = false;
            picHeart3.Visible = false;
            picHeart4.Visible = false;
            picHeart5.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (wrong == 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Lose!");
        }
    }

    private void btnWordG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void wordGuess_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadwords();                  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's not a lot of code. That's the problem. Make more code. That should fix the problem. Most people here don't like to make code from scratch. We prefer that you make all the code, run into a mystery error in the code, and then come here for help.

Comment: I actually deleted my full code and restarted from scratch quite a few times. Ill add it back then post again.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem consists solely of interacting with text boxes. You'd have the same problem without any randomness involved.  In that case, the `random` tag is not relevant to your actual problem, and should be removed.